# Golang run sql query in >100 mysql instances with goroutine

Tags: python, mysql, go

I need to run a mysql query to retrieve data from >100 mysql instances, it's just a sample select query and returns around 1k rows from each instance. Is that possible to run the sql query to get data from all the 100 mysql instances concurrently with goroutine in Golang?

The sql can be very easy like this: `select * from table1`

I tried to do the same thing in python with asyncio since they are mostly io blocking tasks, it's faster than the synchronous code but still slow to me. Will Golang channel be faster than Python asyncio for this case?

Comment: 100 is a lot.  The _system_ overhead of handling 100 processes competing with each other may lead to disappointing performance.  What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: We however do not know what is _not_ slow to you, as there is nothing to compare here. Most likely running 100 mysql instances will be equally slow regardless of the language you are calling them from.

Comment: I would probably solve the problem differently, using some sort of sync, but definetly doable. 
And I'd say it depends on how you will connect to the different instances. Are the instances grouped on different machines or is it one machine per instance?